# Evaluation of an oriented surface integral

Tags: integration, surfaces, greens-theorem, stokes-theorem

I am having a bit of trouble understanding example 1 in Paul's Calculus Notes page on surface integral:

http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/SurfIntVectorField.aspx

I understand how to do surface integrals by parametrizing the surface; however, in the problem, the author directly calculates the normal vector by finding the gradient and simply ends up taking the dot product between the vector field and the normal vector.

I understand how this may work if the normal vector is normalized to a unit vector, and he does divide by the magnitude; however, I don't understand why he is multiplying by the magnitude of the normal vector again and saying that the magnitude will "cancel out."

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> I understand how to do surface integrals by parametrizing the surface; however, in the problem, the author directly calculates the normal vector by finding the gradient...

The surface area element of the graph of a function $ z=f\,(x,y)$ is

$$dA= \left\|{\partial \mathbf{r} \over \partial x}\times {\partial \mathbf{r} \over \partial y}\right\| \mathrm dx\, \mathrm dy $$

where $\mathbf{r}=(x, y, z)=(x, y, f(x,y))$. So that ${\partial \mathbf{r} \over \partial x}=(1, 0, f_x(x,y))$, and ${\partial \mathbf{r} \over \partial y}=(0, 1, f_y(x,y))$. Then,

$$dA = \left\|\left(1, 0, {\partial f \over \partial x}\right)\times \left(0, 1, {\partial f \over \partial y}\right)\right\| \mathrm dx\, \mathrm dy
\\
=\left\|\left(-{\partial f \over \partial x}, -{\partial f \over \partial y}, 1\right)\right\| \mathrm dx\, \mathrm dy
\\
=\sqrt{\left({\partial f \over \partial x}\right)^2+\left({\partial f \over \partial y}\right)^2+1}\, \, \mathrm dx\, \mathrm dy$$

(see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_integral#Surface_integrals_of_scalar_fields))

Comment: Right, so that is the magnitude of the gradient and represents the normal vector. I don't understand why the author can use the gradient directly instead of using its normalized version (gradient/magnitude) when calculating flux.